# Is the astronomical magnitude identical to the distance?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, dark-energy, distance

Why do astrophysicists use Magnitude rather than the actual distance to calculate intergalactic parameters? The magnitude is the relative brightness and has no units, the typical distance requires the unit; pc or kpc or Mpc. It seems that hundreds of astronomers use the magnitude rather than distance to estimate astrophysical parameters.

Comment: Doesn't the magnitude tell you something about the star itself?

Comment: @KyleKanos Not really, especially not without knowing the spectrum. There are too many free parameters: radius, temperature, composition, extinction due to dust, etc.

Comment: @probably_someone you've clearly missed the point

Comment: @KyleKanos What is the point, then?

Comment: @probably_someone is magnitude a measure of distance or the brightness of an object?

Comment: @KyleKanos Depends on what you mean by "brightness." It's certainly a measure of the _apparent_ brightness of an object, as seen from Earth, but this doesn't necessarily tell you something about "the star itself," especially if there's intervening dust.

Comment: because it’s more convenient.  Mind you there are all kinds of magnitude (apparent, absolute, etc) so some clarifications are required.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero - yes it is more convenient, but the parameters one estimates by using any magnitude rather than distance are always wrong. Why bother to collect the SNe Ia data only to publish wrong results?

Comment: @KyleKanos Magnitude is a measure of brightness and not a measure of distance. The magnitude may be converted to proper distance but most astronomers do not bother with this easy step.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the apparent magnitude of a certain astronomical body within a certain wavelength band is just a rescaling of its brightness in that wavelength band as seen from Earth.  It depends on a few different factors: the astronomical body's luminosity, meaning the total amount of power radiated (which is dependent on things like its radius, temperature, and composition), its distance from Earth, and the amount of dust in the way (the reduction in brightness due to intervening material is usually called "extinction"). So no, in general apparent magnitude is not identical to distance; however, in certain situations, apparent magnitude can be *converted* into distance, and in those situations this conversion is often the most straightforward way to obtain the distance.

Extinction due to dust is reasonably well modeled for most of the astronomically-relevant wavelength bands; in fact, there are whole teams of expert astronomers who spend their careers mainly focused on studying interstellar dust and correcting magnitudes for the effects of extinction. The main idea is that extinction is highly wavelength-dependent, so we can actually measure how much dust is in the way, without knowing the distance between us and the object, by comparing different parts of the spectrum of the object to the spectrum of similar nearby objects unaffected by extinction. So extinction-corrected apparent magnitudes are dependent only on distance and luminosity.

This should suggest that, if you have a body whose luminosity is *known*, then the extinction-corrected apparent magnitude is only dependent on distance. As such, you can get the distance to such a body directly by measuring the extinction-corrected apparent magnitude. Fortunately, many such objects exist. For example, a certain class of variable star (called "classical Cepheids" by the constellation in which they were first discovered) vary their brightness with a frequency that depends directly on their luminosity. So, by measuring the frequency of the brightness oscillations of these stars, you can obtain their luminosity, which means you can convert apparent magnitude into distance.

For longer distances, the "standard candle," as it is often called, is the Type Ia supernova. Since such an event is caused by a white dwarf exploding once it reaches a certain size, the amount of energy released in such an explosion ($10^{44}$ J) is known. In addition, the light curve (graph of luminosity vs. time) is unique, varies little from event to event, and is easily identified, so it's possible to determine the peak luminosity and compare it to the peak apparent magnitude of the explosion to estimate the distance. In this way, astronomers can turn apparent magnitudes into distances.

Comment: Thanks to probably_someone, for a pretty good explanation of astronomical magnitude, who wrote "... which means you can convert apparent magnitude into distance."  Yes, true enough, I agree. My question boils down to the fact that many, many astronomers do not bother to convert the apparent magnitude into a proper distance required for calculations. They simply use the value of the magnitude for parameter estimation, parameters such as the Hubble constant. How can they do that and trust parameters estimated from these calculations? If asked I can provide example articles in ApJ and A&A.

Comment: @MikeSmith Looking at the examples you gave: In Reiss et al, they give you the formula that they used to calculate the distance in 4.1, equation 1. They _plotted_ the difference between apparent magnitude $m$ and absolute magnitude $M$ because $m-M$ is directly related to the log of the distance $d$ through the formula $m-M=5\log_{10}\left(\frac{d}{10\text{ pc}}\right)$. This is why the quantity $m-M$ is called the _distance modulus_. They likely chose to plot it this way because it shows a linear relationship.

Comment: Not only did they use the distance modulus for display purposes but also to calculate the parameters, such as the Hubble constant, Omega_m and Lambda.  The FRW model used to estimate parameters, as presented by Riess and Perlmutter, is based on distance not modulus. They did not use the distances. Please do the math yourself - best to not trust what you think the authors did, but calculations you do yourself. If you unable to do the calculations you might take a look at https://youtu.be/Y1nEQmg2yJA and https://youtu.be/IN0jqhqjW3Y

Comment: You might label the value for m-M as the distance modulus, but it is still a modulus and not the distance. What is the metric associated with the distance modulus? Not m, nor pc, nor Mpc, nor any measure at all.

Comment: @MikeSmith First of all, I don't see where it's specifically said that the distance modulus exclusively was used to calculate those parameters. Can you point to the specific section in each paper that you see this claim? Also, the distance modulus _is_ the distance, relative to a reference distance (which is always 10 pc); specifically, it's 5 times the number you have to multiply 10 pc by to get the distance. If the distance modulus is 0, then the distance is 10 pc. If the distance modulus is 5, then the distance is 100 pc, etc. So anything you do with distance, you can also do with $m-M$.

Comment: @MikeSmith As such, it's perfectly possible to calculate those parameters using the distance modulus only; in each formula, substitute $10\text{ pc}\times 10^{(m-M)/5}$ for the distance.

Comment: probably_someone Your answer is only 1/4 correct. First, astronomers-astrophysicists do not bother do this. Read those two references above and **run your own calculations** and you will see that Riess and Perlmutter and coauthors did not even bother to do what you suggest. Second, by doing as you suggest one automatically diminish the effects of the errors associated with the most distant SNe Ia. So your estimated parameters will still be wrong. So the question remains - why did Riess and Perlmutter and crews not estimate cosmological parameters correctly?

Comment: For some reason you retain the opinion that the distance modulus is the actual distance and then you write the relationship between the distance and the distance modulus. Please think about why the distance modulus carries no metric, not m nor km nor pc nor Mpc. Also, you owe it to yourself to actually do some homework. You can find the data of Riess et al. and Perlmutter et al. at supernovaanalytics.wordpress.com to run your own calculations. If running calculations is too much of a bother then simply watch the two videos listed above.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the actual brightness of an object, and its apparent brightness, you can work out the distance. Often finding the actual brightness is difficult, but even then if you have similar objects their magnitudes imply their relative distances.

Note that in the formulas below all logs are to base 10.

The formula that links magnitude and distance is

m2 - m1 = 5 log(d2/d1)

where m2 and m2 are the magnitudes of the stars and d2 and d1 are their distances (in any units you like - it is a ratio).

There is no absolute scale in any of the above. At one time astronomers used the terms apparent magnitude and absolute magnitude. The apparent magnitude was the magnitude measured on Earth, and by convention the absolute magnitude was defined as the apparent magnitude measured 10 parsec from the star. Apparent magnitude is now just called magnitude (m), and absolute magnitude is called luminosity (M). So, if d0 = 10 parsec and d is in parsec,

m - M = 5 log(d/d0) = 5 log10(d) - 5

This quantity is also called the distance modulus.

When measuring quantities which vary over a large range of scales it is often convenient to use a log scale. The equation gives an obvious scale to use

5 log(d) = (m - M + 5)

In Riess et al the value of M was the same for all the objects examined. This meant that using values of m was equivalent to using values of log(d).

Now we can answer the original questions.

Is astonomical magnitude identical to distance? - No, but in certain circumstances they are equivalent.

Why do astrophysicists use Magnitude rather than the actual distance to calculate intergalactic parameters? - Because in situations where they are equivalent astrophysicists have found it convenient to use the logarithmic scale, and this scale comes more naturally from using magnitude than from using the actual distance values.

Comment: Peter - two examples of the use of magnitude rather than distance for parameter calculation are Riess AG, et al. 1998 Observational evidence from supernovae for an accelerating universe and a cosmological constant. Astronomical Journal Vol.116, pp. 1009-1038 (doi.org/10.1086/300499) and Perlmutter S, et al. 1999 Measurements of Omega and Lambda from 42 high-redshift supernovae. Astrophysical Journal Vol. 517, pp. 565-586 (doi.org/10.1086/307221). I think both articles are now free to the public. Take a good look at the analyses, magnitudes, not distances were used to calculate the parameters.

Comment: A portion of your answer is 100% correct, "Is astonomical magnitude identical to distance? - No,..." unfortunately you continued, blunted your statement with an untrue phrase and  compromised your presentation of proper data handling. Remember any form of magnitude has no units, none. This means **magnitude is not a metric for distance.**

Comment: I use "equivalent" to mean either can be unambiguously converted to the other. Given a known value forM this is true. If M is not known the conversion can still be done, but only in terms of some unknown distance unit. This is not a problem, after all the distances to the planets were only known in terms of an "astronomical unit" formany years.